# Android : I want to remove notification of message

Tags: android, sms, android-notifications

I've made custom message application

so when New message comes, My app works and activity is shown

when i clicked the message button, it shows the list of messages including the new message.

so I want to remove notification of message!

I heard that method cancel() does it.

but I dont know the id of method cancel() about Message Notification.

How can I do it?

```
public void btnPressed(View view)
{
    badge.hide();
    Intent msgIntent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecureMessagesActivity.class);
    startActivity(msgIntent);

    nm.cancel(0);

}
```

Comment: You should use always the same notification Id for your notification, so you will know the id.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass in `cancel` the same `id` you are passing in `notify` method. So if you're doing:

```
mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

then, you should cancel using the id `1`:

```
mNotificationManager.cancel(1);
```